# I'm trying to give url as a parameter in function in flask python but it's showing me this error

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeVQc.png)This is my code where I'm trying to give url as a parameter in function in flask python but it's showing me this error

url=https://www.amazon.ae/s?i=electronics&rh=n%3A11601326031%2Cn%3A11601327031%2Cn%3A12303750031%2Cn%3A15415001031&s=popularity-rank&pd_rd_r=b187273e-a790-4653-a033-f8e1761d7dcd&pd_rd_w=Zu5vY&pd_rd_wg=bNdaX&pf_rd_p=d90dc948-6b98-4678-a0aa-bc9b5bc35ac8&pf_rd_r=CWGRMPG3B91MY0GE7EPM&ref=pd_gw_unk

```
@app.route("/data/<url_add>")
def data(url_add):
print(url_add)
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url_add, headers=headers)
```

Comment: What is the url?

Comment: https://www.amazon.ae/s?i=electronics&rh=n%3A11601326031%2Cn%3A11601327031%2Cn%3A12303750031%2Cn%3A15415001031&s=popularity-rank&pd_rd_r=b187273e-a790-4653-a033-f8e1761d7dcd&pd_rd_w=Zu5vY&pd_rd_wg=bNdaX&pf_rd_p=d90dc948-6b98-4678-a0aa-bc9b5bc35ac8&pf_rd_r=CWGRMPG3B91MY0GE7EPM&ref=pd_gw_unk

Comment: @LinuxGeek That is the link I'm trying to access.

Comment: Also, post the code where you are getting the error and the whole error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass URL in `path parameters`. Which is not convenient.
I am suggesting you to pass it as argument.

Here is the code which might help you.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/data", methods=['GET'])
def data():
    url = request.args.get("url")
    print(url)
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
    return {"ok": True}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**POSTMAN SCREENSHOT**
[image]